# Getting files using SolidWorks PDM API (Python)

Tags: python, com, solidworks, pdm

I'm trying to write a script in python that automatically gets the latest versions of all Excel files in the "Documents" folder in my SolidWorks EPDM vault. Here is my code:

```py
import pythoncom
import win32com.client


def connect_to_vault(vaultName):
    newVault = None

    interface = pythoncom.LoadTypeLib('C:/Program Files (x86)/SOLIDWORKS PDM/EdmInterface.dll')

    for index in range(0, interface.GetTypeInfoCount()):
        type_name = interface.GetDocumentation(index)[0]

        if 'EdmVault5' == type_name:
            type_iid = interface.GetTypeInfo(index).GetTypeAttr().iid
            newVault = win32com.client.Dispatch(type_iid)
            break

    newVault.LoginAuto(vaultName, 0)
    return newVault


def traverse_folder(folder, parent_level="", directory_array=None):
    if directory_array is None:  # First time through
        directory_array = []

    current_directory = parent_level + folder.Name + "\\"

    # Go through all files in current folder
    pdm_file_pos = folder.GetFirstFilePosition()
    # Loop files
    while not pdm_file_pos.IsNull:
        pdm_file = folder.GetNextFile(pdm_file_pos)
        currNm = pdm_file.Name
        # Test for excel file
        if ('.xlsx' not in currNm) and ('.xlsm' not in currNm):
            file_path = 'VAULT\\' + current_directory + currNm
            directory_array.append(file_path)

    # Go through all sub-folders in current folder
    pdm_sub_folder_pos = folder.GetFirstSubFolderPosition()  # Get first sub-folder
    # Loop sub-folders
    while not pdm_sub_folder_pos.IsNull:
        # Get next sub-folder and traverse
        pdm_sub_folder = folder.GetNextSubFolder(pdm_sub_folder_pos)
        traverse_folder(pdm_sub_folder, current_directory, directory_array)
        if len(directory_array) >= 80:
            return directory_array

    return directory_array


def getLatestVersions():
    vault_name = 'VAULT'
    newPath = "C:\\PDM\\"
    folder_path = "VAULT\\Documents\\"

    # Connect
    vault = connect_to_vault(vault_name)

    folder_path = newPath + folder_path
    temp_ProjID = vault.GetFolderFromPath(folder_path)

    # Get list of all files
    filteredFiles = traverse_folder(temp_ProjID)
    
    changedFiles = []  # List of files that have been updated
    # Loop through files & Get Latest Version of each
    for idx, file in enumerate(filteredFiles):

        temp_ProjID = vault.GetFolderFromPath(folder_path)
        temp_DocID = vault.GetFileFromPath(newPath + file, temp_ProjID)[0]

        # Get versions to compare
        currentVersion = temp_DocID.CurrentVersion
        localVersion = temp_DocID.GetLocalVersionNo(newPath + file)

        if localVersion != currentVersion:  # Version mismatch
            
            # --------- THIS LINE THROWS ERROR -------------------
            temp_DocID.GetFileCopy(0, '', temp_DocID.ID, 16, '')
            # ----------------------------------------------------
            changedFiles.append(newPath + file)

        filteredFiles[idx] = newPath + file

    return filteredFiles, changedFiles


if __name__ == "__main__":
    getLatestVersions()
```

It all works until it gets to the GetFileCopy() command, then it gives me this error:

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)

I've tried a bunch of approaches and PDM commands and this is the closest I'm getting. I'm on Windows 11 with Solidworks PDM 2021 using Python 3.7 and win32com

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this just boils down to an incorrect argument, according to the API documentation, the function expects a directory path or the ID of the folder where it should be copied. Instead of the document ID, you need to pass the project (folder) ID.

Corrected Line:

```
temp_DocID.GetFileCopy(0, '', temp_ProjID.ID, 16, '')
```